# How do i add to integers in a list together in python?

Tags: python

I'm really new to python and I'm pretty sure this is a quick fix but im pretty stumped
I'm trying to make a blackjack game using a list for school and i cant find a way to add up the sums of the numbers in the list..
for example:

dealers_hand = [ '1', '4', ]
how would i add the 1 and 4?

I've tried using dealers_hand.pop and then converting it to an int but then
i get met with an error message
I have also heard somewhere to use .split() but that does not work either

any help is appreciated :)

Comment: You mean like via [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functools.html)? Example right there in the docs.

Comment: It looks like you've actually got a list of strings, not integers. Different.

Comment: Vague handwavey descriptions of the error (or lack of description in this case) are not helpful. If you have code that doesn't work, provide a [MCVE].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You asked a "question" and got answers. Still, note that the community here doesn't replace other great online resources such as tutorials and reading books about learning Python. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and ___read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)___ as a reference on how to ask future questions. Also after you've gotten answers don't forget to mark the "best" answer as the _accepted_ answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use:

```
card_sum = sum(int(card) for card in dealers_hand)
```

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: @rfiley7373 If this answered your question please make sure it mark it as being the correct answer. That let's the rest of us know that this question has been answered properly and we don't need to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sum(map(int, dealers_hand))`